# FAQ suggestion: Add links to mathematica.stackexchange.com and physics.stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request

Currently the FAQ says:

> There are certain subjects that, while still being on-topic here, you
>   can get better response on our sister sites:
>
> - Research-level mathematics — Math Overflow
> - Research level Algorithm design, complexity theory, etc — Theoretical
>     Computer Science - Stack Exchange
> - Algorithm implementation/design, computer simulation and modelling,
>     etc — Stack Overflow
> - Statistical analysis — Statistical Analysis - Stack Exchange

I propose that we add a similar item for mathematica.stackexchange.com

Something like:

> - Questions about Mathematica — [Mathematica - Stack Exchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/faq)

---

In the line:

> Physics, engineering and financial questions — it is fine to ask the mathematical model and techniques, but concepts of the field would be off-topic.

I suggest we add a link to https://physics.stackexchange.com/  E.g. like:

> Physics, engineering and financial questions — it is fine to ask the mathematical model and techniques, but concepts of the field would be off-topic.  Physics questions can be asked at [Physics - Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/).

---

Minor comment: in "Research level Algorithm design" above, it should be a lowercase "a".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Done. [space padding to make this an actual answer. Go see the FAQ for the newer version.]

Comment: Excellent! [space padding to make this an actual comment.]

Comment: Could you please also add [cs.se]?

Comment: @Kaveh: done. I also added Computational Science `scicomp`.

Comment: Thanks @Willie :)